# wso2 text/xml > REST TO SOAP

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have a problem with WSO2, I have an application that provides me a WS in a version that takes into account application/soap+xml and another only text/xml.

But when I send the flow, it does not manage to receive it because it is soap+xml, I changed the content type in the message by text/xml, it sends the flow but does not work because wso2 removes the SOAP envelope, I do not see how to do someone has he an idea?

Comment: <property description="messageProperty" name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/soap+xml"/>

by

<property description="messageProperty" name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/xml"/> 

don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the address endpoint format. It could be either `SOAP 11` or `SOAP 12`, which is the SOAP version supported by backend (I believe it's SOAP 11 in your case as it expects `text/xml` content-type).

It can be configured under `Endpoint Configurations` in Endpoints tab in Publisher portal.

You need to select the relevant SOAP version as `Format` under `Message Content`, select `Leave As-Is` as the `Optimize` option under `Message Content` and save the changes. Refer the screenshots below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: i can't change this , i don't this option in endpoint .

Comment: What is the API Manager version you are using? You need to configure this in WSO2 API Manager, not in your endpoint.

Comment: i have WSO2 API Manager v4

Comment: I did the WS again, I was able to change the endpoint in wso2 api manager.But I still have the error.
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><faultcode>S:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: unexpected XML tag. expected: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope but found: {urn:GCE}execute</faultstring></S:Fault></S:Body></S:Envelope>

Comment: Is this from your actual endpoint? Can you paste the complete error and update the question

Comment: it's ok , with the good endpoint , i don't save .... but i have a new problem who is different